# Building a new country in northern Australia, how do we win an information war

Tags: government, politics, geopolitics

I am building a world where a country is seceding from Australia.

The country has over 600 citizens interested in the project, and can get tens of thousands more to join once it launches its "gamified" referral system.

Currently, nobody lives within the area it plans to build our city, it is an uninhabited, unused area with a river and forests and some dirt road access.

The country has a constitution, functioning government, citizenship system and is developing digital banking services, business registration services, and planning to settle its claim.

Once the systems are more developed, the nation will begin to fundraise moderate amounts of money from citizens (selling settlement 'packages' to fund infrastructure) and can get the technical expertise to do most things settlement related.

However, the group does not want to go through a process of democratic reform to do this, as it's not easily possible, and there is no legal framework for a new city to be built, nor a viable method to form a new state. The group does not want to rely on 3rd parties to be created, and would rather take its own initiative to become independent.

**The goal is to secede peacefully from Australia, within a lifetime**

### Winning an information war

The nation needs a large number of nations (limited-recognition, and recognised), organisations, politicians, and informational sources to view it as an independent nation. There is a number of ideas to do this.

- Creating front international organisations, and trying to get limited-recognition states to join, creating notability for all member nations, including ours, and also notability for the international organisation.
- Getting serious news articles written about our project and working with journalists to make us look like a force to be reckoned with, but appeal to the Australian public too.
- Building *'3rd party'* websites with information about nations, and including us in them, so we have enough secondary references to be added to places like Wikipedia, and Google's Knowledge Graph and be referred to as a country.
- Using our technological expertise, we build open-sourced country data packages that include our country inside them, secretly embedding us in thousands of websites and applications around the world.
- Creating 'indexes' (eg: Human Development Index) which include us in sources used by educational institutions, politicians and journalists, further boosting our reputation. One specific index we will create will relate to digital governance, giving our nation a highlight, as this is an area we excel in.
- Seeking diplomatic recognition from other nations, joining as many existing organisations (such as UNPO, ISO, APNIC) as possible.
- Creating our own news organisations, to increase awareness of our project, and to have some news organisation on our side.
- Down the track, lobbying support from politicians.
- Forming a reputable scholarly organisation/university, to promote the political theory and social theory that benefits us.

**What else could we do to win this informational war?**

The country is exploiting a grey area in law that permits them to build a city autonomously and assume full independence, assume it is fully possible to do what the nation plans to do

Comment: Can you add a map to indicate the exact territory you've got in mind for this? Makes it  easier to determine what valuables are in your ground.

Comment: Does Australia have to say anything to this or it's just a British thing? for example, Quebec, who have much more rights and history to by independent but is still not.

Comment: @Hyfnae added the image

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Please elaborate?

Comment: There is a rule here: only one question per post. That rule is very useful for a number of reasons, please try to only ask one question. You can open as many different posts as you like. Try starting with one and then go from there

Comment: Have you read about the [Hutt River Province](http://principality-hutt-river.com/)?  "The Principality of Hutt River is an Independent Sovereign State having seceded from Australia on the Twenty First Day of April 1970..."

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones This is a more serious project.

Comment: @Raditz_35 I don't have time at the moment to do that unfortunately

Comment: Worst case - if you can't secede peacefully, team up with emus and secede by force

Comment: All you have to do is copy paste your post into a word file and then delete the 2 questions with lower priority for now. Once you find the time, ask them. Otherwise, this question will be closed. You can also do this later, posts can be reopened. As I said, this is a very useful and smart rule. If you stay here for a little bit, you will see what it does and why it holds this place together

Comment: Quebec, as a place have much more difference beetwen "them" and rest of Canada to try to be recognised as independent country. and you would need to check how sovereignty is treated in the Commonwealth. Australia might not have a lot to say in it.

Comment: @Raditz_35 ive done that now

Comment: Thanks man! Wish you luck with your question. That one is a bit harder and a lot more thought out than what we get here usually. I hope we get to see more of that kind of question

Comment: Welcome. I think this question is difficult to answer because of the stipulation "what **else**" followed by a complete list of answers. It's great to show your thinking in a question, and it's great to give people a place to start - but it seems you've already answered this very, very thoroughly. Asking "what else" after providing a dozen answers doesn't leave much room for answers.

Answer (score 4):

### There are examples of this, and even current-day movements to secede from the Australia's Federation. It is not inconceivable for what you suggest to happen.

For some while, the [Principality of the Hutt River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Hutt_River) was a self-declared state within a state, inside Western Australia, with a population of around 23 - and you can even visit it as a 'tourist attraction'. However the governments wink and tolerate this, in the end the issue is really recognition by others. (The Australian Tax Office took a dim view on the Principality, and they are currently 'in trouble' for unpaid taxes).

This means **you really do need an incentive for others to recognise you** and can't really try just self-declaring it, even with the technical prowess and 'information war' points described.

On another note, there is actually a very [strong secessionist movement in Western Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secessionism_in_Western_Australia), with a large group of people (notably WA Liberals) wanting to declare Western Australia separate, calling it Westralia. There are strong arguments they say, but they are mostly self serving and debatable:

- The economy of WA is different to the other states, being based more on mining than other industries
- In the 'two-speed economy' a mining boom wealth is sent to the Eastern States, much to the distress of WA

However, the Eastern States don't really agree with this. Also, the economic arguments are debatable, as there is also an argument the WA economy is propped up by Eastern States in a mining bust. So in essence it is fair to say the movement has zero chance, because **you really need the economic case agreed by everyone**.

So given this, you really need the following squared away:

- A very strong, agreed and rock solid economic argument why secession and separation is better for everyone.
- A very strong agreement from everyone (including the rest of Australia) that it is better this way. This means all your information points need to be *for the benefit of the other states*, not yours.

So perhaps some scenarios:

- The area in the North becomes too troublesome economically, and is dragging the whole of the economy down. Now you have an argument to discard it. It would actually be better to 'talk down' your nation than to talk it 'up'.
- There is a strong cultural reason to secede. Perhaps an indigenous nation if reconciliation is not successful? Or a place where the government wants to dump undesirables into a questionable quasi-state? (such as Christmas Island, Manus Island, and other islands). This is somewhat akin to the Australian Government shrinking international maritime borders, in an effort to 'discard' islands so it could dump illegal boat arrivals there.
- Or there is a positive reason to do so, ie. perhaps the nation of Australia suddenly becomes extraordinary pro-UN, has a very strong leadership role in the world, and partitions off a part of itself to headquarter it? (much like the Australian Capital Territory at Federation, but one *outside* Federation)

Comment: So what incentives would you suggest in this case

Comment: So Economic: The area is a drag on the Main Economy. Money keeps being sunk in it and it doesn't come back out. Being independent makes everyone richer. Cultural: The area _should_ be separate for indigenous reasons and it would be difficult to have an argument _not_ to separate.

Comment: Western Australia (WA) was economically supported for most of its time as part of the Commonwealth. The mining boom is recent. The rest of Australia has good reason to consider gaining a share in that newfound wealth is recompense for propping up WA for many decades.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the setting of your story, novel, or game.

In a **realistic** world, forget it. Australia is a stable democracy, recognized by the rest of the world community, and it won't be possible without their consent. As for getting that consent, see what happened when President Trump [suggested](https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/49371324) buying Greenland.

In a suitably **cinematic world**, start with something like [Stark Enterprises](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Stark_Industries). Known worldwide for decades and strongly associated with an ambiguously multinational [force](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D.) that has been saving Earth time and again.

Strike a deal for a [special economic zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_economic_zone). Run that successfully, until they can argue that there **is** a local population, and that this population wants and deserves independence. Having a recognizable population doesn't guarantee independence, see [Catalonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_independence_movement), but it is probably necessary.

Comment: This really doesn’t answer my question, just shuts down the possibility.

Comment: SEZ is not a possibility, I said this group does not want to go through the democratic process because it is not possible

Comment: @DominusVilicus the alternative to following the democratic process is for the legitimate government of the area to round them all up and sling em in jail. People have been seeking independence and statehood since forever, so there are no shortage of historical and present-day examples of how wanting stuff isn't enough to just get it, even if the people doing the wanting are really earnest libertarians and feel like they really deserve it.

Comment: @StarfishPrime the country is not breaking any laws and exists in a grey area of responsibility

Comment: @DominusVilicus to obtain independence without the actual government of the area just giving it to you, you will have to break laws. You either work with that government to get what you'd like, or you submit to their laws, and their governance, and pay taxes to them.

Comment: It can avoid taxation by using our own currency, and assume the laws we break exist in a grey area which will be nearly impossible for the Australian government to enforce for various reasons

Comment: @DominusVilicus, sovereign states get to **define** what treason and tax evasion is in their jurisdiction, and they don't take kindly to people who try to do an end run around the revenue officers and money-laundering laws with a self-made currency.

Comment: Yes, and the nation is not committing treason under Australian law because it is not using violence, which is a prerequisite

Comment: It’s not tax evasion either. We are making no AUD, meaning we are not generating income and therefore ineligible to be taxed

Comment: @DominusVilicus, if people in a whole region start to trade with something other than Australian Dollars, the tax office will quickly notice and take measures. If such a loophole *was* possible, don't you think corporations and lawyers would have started using it on a large scale?

Comment: @o.m no because a corporation couldn’t enforce usage of their currency, but look at bitcoin, the government was useless in being able to tax it. They could only tax it once it was transferred back to AUD

Comment: @DominusVilicus The sad reality of asking a question is that sometimes the answer is no. You can use as many if's and but's as you want, but your essentially going to be spending billions to trillions of Australian dollars to pay Australians workers to build Australian Infrastructure using Australian materials on Australian territory. Plus, at the worst case, the Australian military roll in and take everything back.

Comment: @DominusVilicus, I presume you want to write a story or game. If this is a real-world plan, it would be silly do refine it with help from Worldbuilding SE. Novels are **allowed** to depart from reality, but the writer should be aware where that happens.

Comment: @o.m. It doesn't matter, it's a world, based on this current reality. Those are the constraints, and I see no problem with worldbuilding helping plan it, whether it's real or not